# Laggy when lid is closed and on external monitor (on the MacBook)

Tags: power-management, mac, macbook, macbook-pro, gnome-power-manager

I am running 17.10 on a MacBook 11,4. The problem is that the mouse pointer and application UI (with any app) is laggy, which is likely some power manager thing as it only happens when the lid is closed and I am working on an external monitor. I'm only seeing 1/3 of total memory being used and CPU use is also little. I was trying to follow many of the steps from the Racter's Medium article, "How to Install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Retina MacBook 11,2" but not everything worked on 17.10 and also the author seemed to want a battery optimized setup while I want a power optimized one. Should I go ahead and edit the tlp config or it's something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that using the MacBook with its screen switched off and the external monitor plugged in almost completely solved this, and using the Compizconfig tool completely solved it. I enabled a couple of settings such as "Mouse position polling" but not sure which one was the actual culprit. Note that I didn't revert any change from the blog mentioned in the question - even though I do see "core temperature above threshold,  CPU clock throttled" messages in the system log while compiling code, the end-user experience is not affected by that.